# Gyroscope Error Propagation: Why not use Euler Angles?

Tags: filters, kalman-filters, imu, ekf

Looking at the EKF formulation for Gyroscopes in more depth I'm wondering, why can't we use Euler Angles in the Error State EKF framework for error and covariance propagation instead of Quaternions? Wouldn't this completely solve the quaternion normalization issue(it's over-parametrized).

Basically my idea is to let the state be represented as a rotation matrix and then create a perturbation rotation matrix parametrized by Euler angles. The only problem I am seeing is how to transform the covariance matrix at each update to re-center the euler angles at 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're missing is that the error state Kalman must still be grounded in the actual state.  From [Quaternion kinematics for the error-state Kalman filter, Solà, 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.02508.pdf), the error state update depends on the actual state value:
$$
\hat {\delta \mathbf x} \leftarrow \mathbf F_x(\mathbf x, \mathbf u)\cdot \hat {\delta \mathbf x} \tag {268}
$$
where $\hat {\delta \mathbf x}$ is the error state and $\mathbf x$ is the actual state.

In this formulation, $\mathbf F_x$ is the Jordanian with respect to $\mathbf x$ of the actual nonlinear state update $\mathbf x \leftarrow \mathbf f(\mathbf x, \mathbf u)$.  So any singular points in $\mathbf x$ -- such as you'd get if your angular representation has a singular point -- is going to mess up the Jordanian, and, hence, your day.

Any 3-element representation of a 3D angle will suffer from a singularity, AKA gimbal lock.  For detail on this, see the Wikipedia page* on Euler angles and search on "singularity".  Then search out the hairy ball theorem.

Further, transformations between Euler orientations in different frames (i.e., body-to-world vs. world-to-body) require a tons of trigonometry, while the same transformations in quaternions is just arithmetic.  Admittedly, it's complicated arithmetic, but it's still just arithmetic.

The cost of using *any* three element representation to represent three dimensional angles is more complicated math, culminating in gnarly singularities.  The cost of using quaternions is having that inconvenient 4th dimension to reconcile.

Pick your poison.

---

* Any good discussion on Euler angles will have a discussion of the singularities.  But that's basically my *definition* of "good" in this context.

Comment: The point of the error state formulation is that it will never get close to the singularity since each update will be small. Your update always starts with the error state at 0.

Comment: Dangit!  I _looked_ for the phrase "error state" in your question before I answered!

Comment: Edits have happened.

Comment: I see what you are referring to, I still don't understand why my idea wouldn't work though. Angular velocity and noise is always given in the local reference frame and you should always be able to transform your covariance to centered at (0,0,0). The only confusing thing is how to transform the covariance matrix after an update to recenter it. I can write out my idea mathematically but it seems like it should be able to work.

Comment: Well, I end my answer with "pick your poison".  So -- give it a try.  There certainly are people who advocate using Euler or other 3-element angular representation schemes in Kalman filters so you won't be without company.  However, I've only _heard_ of folks using 3-element angular representations -- every time I've seen a navigation solution spelled out it's used quaternions.

Comment: The key point would be that the state with respect to global coordinates would be written in terms of a rotation matrix or some other form. I just don't understand why you can't always recenter the filter so that you always start from starting state (0,0,0) during the prediction step. I must be missing something, I will write out a mathematical formulation a little bit later.